# How do you get out of the code of the main storyboard in swift?

Tags: swift, storyboard

On my story board in swift, instead of showing the visual representation of the storyboard, it shows me the code behind the storyboard (not the view controller) does anyone know how to get back to the visual representation?

Answer (score 2):

this is how you can switch it back and forth between code view and interface builder:
[image: this is how you can switch it back and forth between code view and interface builder]

Answer (score 1):

Right click the story board in the leftmost file panel, Open As -> Interface Builder - Storyboard.

Comment: I did that but instead of showing interface builder, it shows none.